# Model class for all database table

Tags: cakephp

Is it necessary to have a model class for each database table in [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP)?

And is it necessary to have one controller for each model class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it necessary to have model class
>   for each database table in cakephp?

Generally, yes. If you wish to retrieve, modify or delete data from a particular table, then the CakePHP way to do it would be to create a model for that particular table and use the built-in methods. Exceptions would be:

- Join tables: If the join tables are very simple, you don't need to create a model for them.
- If for some reason you didn't want to create a model for a few tables, and used the `query` function of another model to access them.

On the contrary: You can have models without tables which can be very useful to validate forms. I never find myself have less number of models than the number of tables I have (minus the simple join tables).

> Is it necessary to have one controller
>   for each model class?

No, it's not. While MVC patterns dictate that each model should be manipulated by its own controller, there are times when a single controller handling more than one model makes the code simpler. An example would be having a **User** model, which *hasOne* **Profile** and *hasMany* **Address**. You could manipulate all 3 models from the `UsersController`:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    var $uses = array('User', 'Profile', 'Address');

    function edit_profile() {
        ...
    }

    function change_address() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Always use MVC as a guiding principle. If you deviate too much from the architecture, things will easily fall apart. However, in the end, clean, organized and working code is what matters. :)

HTH.